# eshell: How to create a git diff patch using the greater-than > symbol

Tags: eshell

Eshell does not seem to have built-in support for the greater-than symbol.  How can I run the command:  `git diff SHA1234567890 > patch.diff`

I could run a separate shell command ...

```
(start-process "git-diff" nil "/bin/bash" "-c" COMMAND-STRING)`
```

... but, I'd like to add Eshell support for creating git diff patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eshell does have support for `>` redirection, however, it connects process output using standard Emacs functions (`start-process`, etc).  With the default setting of `process-connection-type`, this means that it uses a pty to communicate with `git`.  `git` then tries to invoke the pager, which doesn't work so well in the "dumb terminal" that eshell provides.  So, possible solutions:

```
git --no-pager diff SHA1234567890 > patch.diff

(setq process-connection-type nil)
git diff SHA1234567890 > patch.diff
```